# Unittesting the outputs of several functions

Tags: python, unit-testing

Sorry for bothering you guys again, but I am not able to solve this problem by myself.
I need to do unittesting with the outputs of several functions. My (simplified) functions look like this:

```
def myfunc1(input1,input2,input3):
    # processing the inputs
    ...
    # new values are then saved in dictionaries
    mat = {'mat1': mat1, 'mat2': mat2, 'mat3': mat3}
    kat = {'kat1': kat1, 'kat2': kat2, 'kat3': kat3}
    # and are returned
    return mat, kat

def myfunc2(input4,input5,input6):
    # processing the inputs
    ...
    # new values are then saved in dictionaries
    tra = {'tra1': tra1, 'tra2': tra2, 'tra3': tra3}
    lala = {'lala1': lala1, 'lala2': lala2, 'lala3': lala3}
    # and are returned
    return tra, lala
```

How can I now test the following?

- test whether 'mat' and 'tra' have the same dimensions
- test whether 'lala1' and 'kat1' have the same dimensions

EDIT:
This would be a first approach of my unittesting script (:

```
import unittest
from funcscript import *

# my example
class myTests(unittest.TestCase):

    # test whether the size of the first dimension of two dictionary elements are the same 
    def test_comparing(self):    
        self.assertEqual(**WHAT TO DO HERE?**,**AND HERE?**, msg ='')

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by `dimensions`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? So far I only a situation, not any attempts or errors.

Comment: @quamrana, I mean the dimensions of a dictionary element. E.g. within the dictionary "tra", the element "tra1" might have the dimensions 80*100*10.

Comment: @ThePjot, I'm stuck with the problem that in terms of unittesting, I don't know how to compare the outputs of two (or more) functions ;-)

Comment: Well in your testcase you call both functions and save their returns in variables. Then compare the length of those you want to compare.

Comment: @ThePjot, I added another script approach to my first post. But since I am new to python, I struggle a bit with the implementation of what you mean with calling both functions and save their returns in variables...

Comment: What I mean is doing something like this `mat, kat = myfunc1(1, 2, 3)`. And same for the myfunc2. And then assert that what you want to verify :)

Comment: Still don't know what you mean by `dimensions`. Is it some sort of integer? Why did you say `80*100*10` and not `80,000`?

Comment: @quamrana, sorry for the poor description from my side. The value 'tra1' in the dictionary is a 3D-matrix with the dimensions of 80*100*10.

Comment: So how can you tell? Does `tra1` have a member `dimensions()` which returns these as a list or something?

Answer (score 0):

`mat.values()` as dimensions

```
    def test_func1_and_func2(self):
        mat, kat = myfunc1(a, b, c)
        tra, lala = myfunc2(e, f, g)
        self.assertEqual(set(mat.values()), set(tra.values()))
        self.assertEqual(set(kat.values()), set(lala.values()))
```

Comment: Gang, thank you for your feedback! I came up with a similar solution after the inspiration of The Pjot. I assume "a, b, c, e, f, g" are my input parameters. Thank you again

Comment: One last thing: when I run my code, it generates me a 3D model. And depending on the input parameters, that might take a while (~ 1 min.). Does that mean that running the unittesting script will also take that long? Since the corresponding functions should be tested here.

Comment: not all code in `myfuncX` are directly related to the dimensions, you can mock some depending how you will organized your code